# Validating a textfield

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

According to the following code, the name textfield cann't be left blank. When the user clicks on the textfield and decides to leave it blank an error will pop out.

But if the user clicks on the button directly without clicking on the textfield, it gets submitted and the error message will not be displayed. So what i want to do is to alert the user when the user clicks on the submit button, if he/she has left blank on the `name` textfield.

```
{   
  xtype:'textfield',
  name:'name',
  label:'name',
  required: true,
  listeners: {
      blur: function(thisTxt, eventObj) {
             var val= thisTxt.getValue();
             if ( val.length==0) {
                     // display alert
             } 
      }
  }
}]
},
{
  xtype:'button',
  id:'new-note-btn',
  text:'Send',
  ui:'confirm',
  padding:5
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give some `id` property to your `textfield` and do as below code ..

```
xtype:'textfield',
name:'name',
id: 'textId',
.....
......
```

and

```
{
  xtype:'button',
  id:'new-note-btn',
  text:'Send',
  ui:'confirm',
  padding:5,
  listeners : {
       tap : function() {
           if(Ext.getCmp('textId').getValue()=="") {
                // display the alert ..
           }
       }
  }
}
```

**Note** : If this `textfield` happens to  be in your `formpanel`, then you get the `formpanel` values and then try to access this `textfield` value using the `name` property like shown below ..

```
// Assuming formpanel id = 'formPanelId' ...

listeners : {
    tap : function() {
         var values = Ext.getCmp('formPanelId').getValues();
         var nameValue = values.name;
         if(nameValue == "") {
               // display the alert ..
         }
    }
}
```